# Migrate .net core to full .net gives error 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here are steps to reproduce:

1. create new asp.net core web targeting .net core 1.1 runtime
2. publish to azure, it is working
3. edit project file, change `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>`
4. publish it again to the same azure app, it gives error 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance ?

Comment: @BruceChen I have not solved the issue, I have deployed new webs... Currently don't have time to try deleting wwwroot of .net core application and see what is happening, but I highly doubt it will solve the issue. I feel like previous IIS with kestrel configuration is somehow still applied event now IIS is hosting the code...

Comment: Since you deployed both netcore and net to the same web app, there may be some stuff remains. If you do not remove additional files at destination when your deploying via VS or empty your `wwwroot` manually, you may encounter this issue. I just followed your description and I could reproduce your issue. If you have time you could try it and it is useful for other similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using VS2017 for creating the .Net Core web application with the new `*.csproj`. I checked this issue on my side and I could reproduce this issue after deployed to azure web app.

After some trials, I found that change `*.csproj` from `netcoreapp1.1` to `net47` could work on local side. I assumed that there be some stuff remains under my web app, I tried to change the publish settings and choose "Remove additional files at destination" for **File Publish Options**, or you could leverage [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) and navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` via **Debug console**, then empty the `wwwroot` folder. Upon the cleaning, redeploy your web application, then your web app could work as expected.